# Binding error in model class while bind data through Util class

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I got null value when my I bind view to the model class. Basically I want to change format of the date using binding, but the function where I call it give the null value. But when I don't use the converter function it works well and show me the unformat date.

Here is my Model class:

public class HomeWorkOrderModel {

```
public String status;
public String message;

public Result result;


public Result getResult() {
    return result;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}


public void setResult(Result result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public class Result{

    public String totalOrders;
    public String totalVenues;

    public List<Orders> orders;


    public String getTotalOrders() {
        return totalOrders;
    }

    public void setTotalOrders(String totalOrders) {
        this.totalOrders = totalOrders;
    }

    public String getTotalVenues() {
        return totalVenues;
    }

    public void setTotalVenues(String totalVenues) {
        this.totalVenues = totalVenues;
    }

    public List<Orders> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<Orders> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    public class Orders{

        public String liveDbWorkOrderId;
        public String assignedBy;
        public String workorderDueDate;
        public String completedVenues;
        public String operationId;
        public String serviceProviderId;
        public String workorderStatus;
        public String totalVenues;

        public String getTotalVenues() {
            return totalVenues;
        }

        public void setTotalVenues(String totalVenues) {
            this.totalVenues = totalVenues;
        }

        public String getLiveDbWorkOrderId() {
            return liveDbWorkOrderId;
        }

        public void setLiveDbWorkOrderId(String liveDbWorkOrderId) {
            this.liveDbWorkOrderId = liveDbWorkOrderId;
        }

        public String getAssignedBy() {
            return assignedBy;
        }

        public void setAssignedBy(String assignedBy) {
            this.assignedBy = assignedBy;
        }

        public String getWorkorderDueDate() {
            return workorderDueDate;
        }

        public void setWorkorderDueDate(String workorderDueDate) {
            this.workorderDueDate = workorderDueDate;
        }

        public String getCompletedVenues() {
            return completedVenues;
        }

        public void setCompletedVenues(String completedVenues) {
            this.completedVenues = completedVenues;
        }

        public String getOperationId() {
            return operationId;
        }

        public void setOperationId(String operationId) {
            this.operationId = operationId;
        }

        public String getServiceProviderId() {
            return serviceProviderId;
        }

        public void setServiceProviderId(String serviceProviderId) {
            this.serviceProviderId = serviceProviderId;
        }

        public String getWorkorderStatus() {
            return workorderStatus;
        }

        public void setWorkorderStatus(String workorderStatus) {
            this.workorderStatus = workorderStatus;
        }

        public String getWorkorderAssignedDate() {
            return workorderAssignedDate;
        }

        public void setWorkorderAssignedDate(String workorderAssignedDate) {
            this.workorderAssignedDate = workorderAssignedDate;
        }

        public String workorderAssignedDate;





    }



}
```

}

Here is my XML code:

In XML:

```
                <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center|start|top"
                    android:id="@+id/enddate"
                    android:textColor="@color/tbmgrey"

                    android:text="@{TbmUtils.changeTimeformat(model.workorderAssignedDate)}"
                    android:textSize="13sp"

                    />
```

I have import the TbmUtils and my model class:

```
    <variable
        name="model"
        type="com.tbmsr.ui.home.HomeWorkOrderModel.Result.Orders" />

    <import type="com.tbmsr.utils.TbmUtils"/>

</data>
```

Here is my TbmUtil class:

```
public class TbmUtils {


    public static String changeTimeformat(String inpTime){


        Log.v("dataDate",inpTime+"");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd//yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        SimpleDateFormat targetDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            Date date = dateFormat.parse(inpTime);
            return targetDateFormat.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }

}
```

Here in log it always receive null value

Comment: The new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd//yyyy)", Locale.ENGLISH); 
has 2 "//" between day and year . Maybe thats the issue.

Comment: Please show the code for your model class.

Comment: check what is the initial value of workorderAssignedDate in your model while binding to view

Comment: I have added my model class. Please tell me whats going wrong

Comment: No @ahmad issue is not at that point. Even at  Log.v("dataDate",inpTime+"") it gives me null value